# Kindle for PC installed via winetricks won't sync

Tags: wine

I am a new user to Ubuntu 16.04 and used winetricks to install the Kindle app and it starts up just fine, Amazon makes it a little hard to register by generating a random one time new password, which I did and it seemed to be successful and Amazon verifies the existence of this new Kindle for PC app but when I try to sync the library it gives me an unable to connect message.  If I close the app and restart, it goes to the registration process again, creates yet another Kindle for PC version and repeats the entire frustrating process.

I'm hoping someone has already solved these problems and can tell me what I need to do to make it work.

Comment: Also wineHQ is the best source of information - See also https://www.hiroom2.com/2016/09/26/ubuntu-16-04-run-kindle-for-pc-windows-with-wine/ and https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=10597 . On the wine HQ you need to use the same version of both wine and Kindle app for it to work . Look up the specific version of Kindle - example - https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=34635

Comment: I agree that the linked question is highly relevant but **no duplicate**. I'm voting to reopen.

Comment: I deleted the rant part. If you have problems with a close vote visit chat or post it on meta. Same for my edit should you disagree.

Answer (score 1):

You may close this question if you wish.  I think the problem is that the version of Kindle for PC used by winetricks is too old.  I followed the instructions from one of the posts in the list of solutions to making Kindle work that my question was said to duplicate - specifically the one that starts with creating a 32 bit wineprefix, downloaded the last version of the installer that works on Windows XP (1.15) and after following the rest of the instructions now have a working version of Kindle for PC.  It is possible that replacing the installer in winetricks with the 1.15 version might be all that is required but since this process worked I didn't try it.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon regularly retires old Kindle versions. You can get the newest versions installed and running by creating missing directory in `AppData` (this hint was found by someone who debugged this somewhere in bugzilla):

```
mkdir -p "{WINEPREFIX}/drive_c/users/{USER NAME}/AppData/Local/Amazon/Kindle"
```

https://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?t=29102